# Magento 2 SSH reindexing not working?

Tags: database, cli, ssh, php-7.3, magento2.3.6

I just installed a Magento 2.3.6 version. and I tried to run the Command Reindexing but it's not working. I tried with diff commands like cache clear and flush none of the commands are not working through SSH. How can i achieve this thing. Can anyone help me with it please.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy these commands and run

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media  generated/ app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media generated/ app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Then Run

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```